# Pandas how to aggregate more than one column

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the snippet:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'userid': [1,1,1,2,2], 'order_id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'fee': [2,1,5,3,1]})
```

I'd like to group based on userid and count the 'order_id' column and sum the 'fee' column:

```
test.groupby('userid').order_id.count()
test.groupby('userid').fee.sum()
```

Is it possible to perform these two operations in one line of code so that I can get a resulting df looks like this：

```
userid    counts    sum
...
```

I've tried pivot_table:

```
test.pivot_table(index='userid', values=['order_id', 'fee'], aggfunc=[np.size, np.sum])
```

It gives something like this:

```
       size             sum
       fee  order_id    fee order_id
userid              
1       3      3          8 6
2       2      2          4 9
```

Is it possible to tell pandas to use np.size & np.sum on one column but not both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `rename` columns:

```
d = {'order_id':'counts','fee':'sum'}
df = test.groupby('userid').agg({'order_id':'count', 'fee':'sum'})
         .rename(columns=d)
         .reset_index()
print (df)
   userid  sum  counts
0       1    8       3
1       2    4       2
```

But better is aggregate by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), because [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) is used if need exclude `NaN`s:

```
df = test.groupby('userid')
         .agg({'order_id':'size', 'fee':'sum'})
         .rename(columns=d).reset_index()
print (df)
   userid  sum  counts
0       1    8       3
1       2    4       2
```